# add step to checkitout

Tags: magento, checkout

My company have just baught [Ivan's CheckItOut extension](http://www.ecomdev.org/2011/05/31/check-out-our-checkitout.html), and I'm trying to add a step in it.
Actually, I did have this step integrated into "regular" OPC.

Looking at the extension's code, I see that there is a `addCheckoutStepToLayout` method used in the layout checkitout.xml file. If I had this line into `checkout.layout` block:

```
<action method="addCheckoutStepToLayout"><layout>right-bottom</layout><step>points</step></action>
```

the step is added, but I'm trying to add it via my extension layout .xml file.
So I've tried updating the checkitout handle:

```
<ecomdev_checkitout_layout>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="checkout.layout">
            <action method="addCheckoutStepToLayout"><layout>right-bottom</layout><step>points</step></action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</ecomdev_checkitout_layout>
```

updating the block through regular `checkout_onepage_index` handle:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="checkout.layout">
            <action method="addCheckoutStepToLayout"><layout>right-bottom</layout><step>points</step></action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

with and without `<reference name="content">`, but no luck until now.
I'd be glad reading your suggestions, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I asked the author directly, and the solution was quite simple.
The block wasn't created yet when I was trying to update it through my module's layout file: I've made it depends on Ecomdev_Checkitout and everything is working fine now.